# Writing special characters from one batch file to another

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am trying to write one batch file from another, using `echo`. However, there is one line with special characters that I cannot work out how to write.

I have the following line:

```
echo >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system" >> "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\OrchestrationCleanUp.bat"
```

But what gets written to the target file is:

```
 "C:\Windows\system32\cacls.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\config\system"
```

It should be:

```
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
```

I have tried putting it in double quotes.

I have tried putting ^ in front of the >

I have tried putting it in a variable and escaping it with double quotes

I have tried putting it in a variable and using ! at each end

I have tried putting it in a variable and using a : at the end of the variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The special characters need to be escaped with `^` and `%` signs have to be doubled.  Try this:

The `(` directly after echo stops issues with some leading characters.

```
echo(^>nul 2^>^&1 "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\cacls.exe" "%%SYSTEMROOT%%\system32\config\system" >> "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\OrchestrationCleanUp.bat"
```